# Navigator.pop(context,result) ERROR : type 'user' is not a subtype of type 'bool?' of 'result'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass an object by closing the interface I did navigator.pop(context , result) but I have this error

> ======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
> The following _TypeError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> type 'User' is not a subtype of type 'bool?' of 'result'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      LocalHistoryRoute.didPop (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart)
#1      _RouteEntry.handlePop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2896:16)
#2      NavigatorState._flushHistoryUpdates (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3868:22)
#3      NavigatorState.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4910:7)
#4      Navigator.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2432:27)
#5      _DistributeurListState.build.. (package:electrosteel_project/widget/point_de_vente/distributeur_list.dart:312:39)
#6      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1005:21)
#7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:613:11)
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:298:5)
#10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:269:7)
#11     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:157:27)
#12     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:449:20)
#13     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:425:22)
#14     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:329:11)
#15     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:380:7)
#16     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:344:5)
#17     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:302:7)
#18     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:285:7)
#22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:170:10)
#23     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:331:7)
#24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#b4118
debugOwner: GestureDetector
state: ready
won arena
finalPosition: Offset(150.9, 333.7)
finalLocalPosition: Offset(150.9, 93.0)
button: 1
sent tap down

```
 onTap: () {

                         Navigator.pop(context,userList[index]);

                      },
```

Comment: Can you show how you push the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `PointdeVente` object to `bool` object

I think you're using like this

```
bool? result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(YourScreen.route):
```

and in `YourScreen` you pop like this

```
Navigator.pop(context,PointdeVente());
```

You have to do something like this.
Example:

```
PointdeVente? result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(YourScreen.route):
```

if you are expecting `PointdeVente` then you should pop like this in `YourScreen`

```
Navigator.pop(context,PointdeVente());
```